# Can I mark a template field in MediaWiki in a way that it only shows when no value is filled?

Tags: lua, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm editing the Wikimedia template for {{[Property Proposal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Module:Property_proposal)}} on Wikidata.

When there's no example filled in the template the template says "missing".
This is achieved by having the field marked with "required = true,"

I would like to have a similar message on the "|subpage = ?" when that field is missing, however I don't want it to show anything when the field is filled (then the content of the field shouldn't be visible to the user.

Is there a way to get this outcome?

Comment: Something like `hidden = true` and then make `makeRow` return early when `rowparams.hidden` is true?